# How to delete rects/sprites with python and pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am working on a game and I wanted to add an ammo box that randomly spawns.  so far the box spawns as expected and if you move over it, it is removed and gives you 200+ ammo.  However, it is only supposed to give 50 ammo.  Then later in the game when the player goes back to that spot they continue to get more ammo.  If I just sit there I end up getting 1000+ ammo.

Here is my ammo class:

```
class Ammo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, player = None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        pass
```

and here is the game loop:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        screen_width = 850
        screen_height = 640

        place_ammo = False

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (screen_width,screen_height) )

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

        #-----

        self.all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.blitwave = 1

        # --- create sprites ---

        self.background = Background()

        self.player = Player(self.screen.get_rect(), 0, 370)
        self.all_sprites_list.add(self.player)
        self.ammo = Ammo(self.screen.get_rect(),random.randrange(10,screen_width),random.randint(10,screen_height - 10))
        self.all_sprites_list.add(self.ammo)

        self.ammo_amount = 10
        self.on_screen = 1
        self.score = 0

        self.crosshair = Crosshair()

    def bullet_create(self, start_pos, mouse_pos):
        bullet = Bullet(start_pos, mouse_pos)

        self.all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
        self.bullet_list.add(bullet)

    def bullets_update(self):
        for bullet in self.bullet_list:

            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, self.block_list, True)
            screen_width = 850
            screen_height = 640

            for block in block_hit_list:
                self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                self.all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                self.score += 1
                self.on_screen -= 1
                self.ammo_chance = self.ammo_amount * 5
                if self.ammo_chance > 0:
                    self.drop = random.randint(1, self.ammo_chance)
                    print(self.drop)
                if self.drop > 0 and self.drop < 2:

                    print('ammo drop')
                    self.ammo = Ammo(self.screen.get_rect(),random.randrange(10,screen_width),random.randint(10,screen_height - 10))
                    self.all_sprites_list.add(self.ammo)

                if bullet.rect.y < -10:
                    self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                    self.all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------

    def run(self):
        screen_width = 850
        screen_height = 640

        #wave
        self.wave = 1
        self.wave_no = 2
        self.wave_running = True
        block = Block(BLUE, random.randrange(100, screen_width), random.randrange(10, screen_height-10), self.player)

        self.block_list.add(block)
        self.all_sprites_list.add(block)

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.cash = 1
        self.health = 100
        self.ammo_amount = 10

        RUNNING = True
        PAUSED  = False

        while RUNNING:
            # --- events ---
            if self.player.health <= 0:
                RUNNING = False
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = PAUSED

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        PAUSED = True

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        PAUSED = not PAUSED

                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and self.ammo_amount > 0:
                    self.bullet_create(self.player, event.pos)
                    self.ammo_amount -= 1

                self.cash = self.score * 5

                if self.on_screen == 0:
                    for i in range(self.wave_no):
                        block = Block(BLUE, random.randrange(100, screen_width), random.randrange(10, screen_height-10), self.player)

                        self.block_list.add(block)
                        self.all_sprites_list.add(block)
                        self.on_screen += 1

                    self.wave_div = int(self.wave_no / 2)
                    self.wave_no += self.wave_div
                    self.wave += 1

                #wave font 
                font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 34)
                self.text_pause = font.render("WAVE " + str(self.wave) * self.blitwave, -1, RED)
                self.text_pause_rect = self.text_pause.get_rect(center=self.screen.get_rect().center) # center text


                #health font
                self.text_health = font.render("|" * self.player.health, -1, RED)

                #score font
                self.text_score = font.render("SCORE " + str(self.score), -1, BLACK)

                #cash font
                self.text_cash = font.render("CASH " + str(self.cash), -1, GREEN)

                #ammo font
                self.text_ammo = font.render("AMMO " + str(self.ammo_amount), -1, RED)

                # send event to player
                self.player.event_handler(event)

            if not PAUSED:
                self.all_sprites_list.update()
                self.bullets_update()

            player_rect = pygame.Rect(self.player.rect.x, self.player.rect.y, 20, 20)
            block_rect = pygame.Rect(block.rect.x, block.rect.y, 20, 20)

            if player_rect.colliderect(block_rect):
                self.player.health = self.player.health - 3

            if player_rect.colliderect(self.ammo.rect):
                self.ammo_amount += 50
                self.all_sprites_list.remove(self.ammo)

            self.crosshair.update()

            # --- draws ---
            self.background.draw(self.screen)
            self.all_sprites_list.draw(self.screen)

            #must be last
            self.screen.blit(self.text_pause, (10, 610))
            self.screen.blit(self.text_score, (700, 585))
            self.screen.blit(self.text_cash, (700, 560))
            self.screen.blit(self.text_ammo, (700, 610))
            self.screen.blit(self.text_health, (10, 10))
            self.crosshair.draw(self.screen)

            pygame.display.update() # use flip() OR update()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(70)

        # --- quit ---

        pygame.quit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sprite is indeed removed but self.ammo which is called to check for collision is still working even after the sprite is removed. Here's what I'd do:

```
if self.ammo and player_rect.colliderect(self.ammo.rect):
        self.ammo_amount += 50
        self.all_sprites_list.remove(self.ammo)
        self.ammo = None
```

Comment: Sprite.kill() will remove it from all sprite groups for you. Ex: `ammo.kill()`